Any update for fixing this issue besides the disabling Secure Implicit connection?
The timing of this bug is awful as I am deploying a new Inventory App and I really don't want to have to disable SQL Security to allow the blob storage to work.
I have tried loading previous versions but it doesn't look like they are updated in Published version history. I have tried removing and re-adding Blob Storage connector and creating new Blob connection with Entra verification and tried using Blob connection with Azure key authentication.

What is the issue exactly?
